# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 Stack Trace: Class. line 33, column 1

Tags: class

I am trying to use rollup help enable real time. To do this the app (rolluphelper) wants to install a trigger and a class onto the opportunity object.

But in deployment it fails with the following error

> System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 Stack Trace:
>   Class.AutoConvertLeadsTest.createnewlead: line 33, column 1

Thats class was a test class written by previous dev team as part of the initial build. I have been able to get most classes from sandbox over but it looks like this one is being prevented because there is a trigger with it. The classes i did get over we part of VF pages

Below is the full test class that the error is pointing to

```
@isTest 
  public class AutoConvertLeadsTest{
  static testMethod void createnewlead() {
  User userToCreate = [Select id from user where profile.name='System Administrator' Limit 1];

  Test.startTest();    
  Lead leadToCreate =new Lead();
  List<id> Ids= New List<Id>();
  leadToCreate.ownerid= userToCreate.id;
  leadToCreate.FirstName ='John';
  leadToCreate.LastName ='Spencer';
  leadToCreate.LeadSource='Partner Referral';
  leadToCreate.Rating='';
  leadToCreate.Status='Qualified';
  leadToCreate.Territory__c = 'Sydney';
  leadToCreate.Lead_Generator__c= 'Utku';
  //leadToCreate.Street ='Pit';
  leadToCreate.Street_name__c ='Pit';
  //leadToCreate.City ='Sydney CBD';
  //leadToCreate.PostalCode ='2000'; 
  leadToCreate.PostCode__c ='2000';    
  leadToCreate.Suburb_Name__c ='Sydney CBD';  
  leadToCreate.Appointment_Date__c = system.today();
  insert leadToCreate; 

  Ids.add(leadToCreate.id);

  List <Lead> convertedLead = [SELECT id, IsConverted, ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId, ConvertedOpportunityId
                               FROM Lead 
                               WHERE IsConverted =true
                               AND id = :leadToCreate.id];

  System.assertNotEquals(convertedLead.get(0).ConvertedAccountId,  null );
  System.assertNotEquals(convertedLead.get(0).ConvertedContactId,  null );
  System.assertNotEquals(convertedLead.get(0).ConvertedOpportunityId,  null );

  Test.stopTest();
 }
}
```

And below is the actual trigger that is associated with that class

```
Public class AutoConvertLeads
{
@InvocableMethod
public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)
{
    LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];
    List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new List<Database.LeadConvert>();
    for(id currentlead: LeadIds){
            Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
            Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);                
            Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel); 
            MassLeadconvert.add(Leadconvert);
    }

    if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) {
        List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr = Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);
    }
}
```

}

So my question is how can I edit the test class in sandbox so that it no longer points to "createnewlead: line 33, column 1"

I am assuming if I can edit (repoint) that older test class I can then push that in to production and going forward I will be able to deploy futher triggers and classes with out having hitting that older test class.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger is not a "trigger" in the meaning of Salesforce. It is an Invoable Method which can be used by flows, through api, .... It is not triggered automatically. [Here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) is a Trailhead Badge for Triggers.

So your second Class with the invocable Method is not the issue of the problem.  To anlyse the issue, follow these Steps:

1. Login to Sandbox
2. Open Developer Console
3. Run Test
4. View Log-File (Tab on the left bottom)

I would assume that there is actually a trigger which causes the issue. The Log file will tell it.

Hint: Developer Console or the Setup in Salesforce will show you all "real" trigger.